# How to stop img src from using current URL plus URL in script

Tags: javascript, image, url, html, src

I have an image inside a `div` tag so that on clicking this image, javascript shows/hides another `div` tag each time this image is clicked.
This scripting is used in a Widget on Wordpress, so it is present on every page of the website.

The problem is, the image inside this `div` tag doesn't show.
I have right clicked the 'no image' icon and chosen 'open image in new tab' and the URL is saying:
`www.DOMAIN.com/www.DOMAIN.com/image`
rather than what is written in the `img src`, which is `www.DOMAIN.com/image`.

If I change it the `src URL` to `=image` it works, but if I try this from any other page, it includes that page too
i.e.
`www.DOMAIN.com/contact/image`
and this isn't where the image is found.

Is there a bit of coding I can put in the `div` tag, a tag or `img` tag or similar that will use the absolute location that I have specified?

Comment: I would recommend showing us some code and the community can assist you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `http://` in front of your `src` attribute. For example, `src="http://DOMAIN.com/image` instead of `src="DOMAIN.com/image"`.

Comment: After all day searching and it was as simple as that!
Thanks that worked.

I have also found a work around of setting a base href around the image tag. (was just about to list it on here and saw your answer)

Thanks arxanas!

Comment: Don't use the `base` tag.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag